# Join two tables with null values - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables as below. I want to join these two for the date 2/04/2021 as like in the output table.
There are chance to get null values for any of the table as shown in the output.

student_details

```
Auto_id    StudentID    StudentName         LastAttendedDate
1            AAA          RAGHAV           8/25/2020 1:40:35 AM
2            BBB          VARUN            2/04/2021 5:40:23 AM
3            AAA          RAGHAV           2/04/2021 1:40:25 AM
4            AAA          RAGHAV           2/04/2021 3:40:35 AM
5            BBB          VARUN            10/01/2021 9:40:35 AM
6            CCC          MAYA             2/04/2021 8:40:35 AM
```

exam_details

```
Auto_id   StudentID      exam_name          exam_date  
1            AAA          PRILIMS          2/04/2021 1:40:35 AM 
2            BBB          MAINS            2/04/2021 5:40:35 AM
3            AAA          PRILIMS          2/04/2021 8:40:35 AM 
4            GGG          PRILIMS          2/04/2021 1:10:35 AM 
5            GGG          MAINS            2/04/2021 2:10:35 AM 
6            GGG          MAINS            2/05/2021 2:10:35 AM
```

Output

```
StudentID        LastAttendedDate          exam_name      exam_date          
  BBB          2/04/2021 5:40:23 AM         MAINS        2/04/2021 5:40:35 AM
  AAA          2/04/2021 1:40:25 AM         PRILIMS      2/04/2021 8:40:35 AM
  AAA          2/04/2021 3:40:35 AM         MAINS        2/04/2021 8:40:35 AM
  CCC          2/04/2021 8:40:35 AM          NULL          NULL
  GGG              NULL                      MAINS       2/04/2021 2:10:35 AM
```

- Should list the StudentID and LastAttendedDate from the table 'student_details' on the date 2/04/2021,
- max(exam_date)(On the date 2/04/2021)  of student  should join to the rows if have.
- Even if no data on the 'student_details' it should show max(exam_date) of student.

Comment: Why are you using an unsupported version of SQL Server?

Comment: Add the T-SQL code you've attempted rather than only list your requirements. Your question will attract downvotes because SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `full join` but after aggregating the two tables:

```
select coalesce(sd.studentid, ed.studentid) as studentid,
       sd.studentname, sd.lastattendeddate,
       ed.exam_name, ed.exam_date
from (select studentid, studentname, max(lastattendeddate) as lastattendeddate
      from student_details
      group by studentid, studentname
     ) sd full join
     (select studentid, exam_name, max(exam_adte) as exam_date
      from exam_details
      group by studentid, exam_name
     ) ed
     on sd.studentid = ed.studentid;
```